# Laravel Eloquent Group By Dates

Tags: laravel, eloquent

i was trying to search on how i can create the same result on this image below on my laravel .I was trying to group it by dates. All the dates that are on the same month will be merge on a single row.
[image]

what i accomplished so far. i cannot merge the dates that has the same months.
**Does any one know how i can accomplished this? thanks**
[image]

Comment: Show the code you have now

Comment: @deczo here is the code. sorry for the late reply

Answer (score 0):

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Test Type</th>
            <?php
                $types = Tblreporttype::all();
            ?>
            @foreach($types as $type)
                <?php  
                    $dates = Tblreportdate::with('tblreporttype')
                        ->groupBy('fDate')
                        ->where('tblreporttype_id', '=', $type->id)
                        ->get();
                ?>
                @foreach($dates as $date)
                <?php
                    $convert = $date->fDate;
                    $my_date = date('M/y', strtotime($convert));
                ?>
                    <th width="100">
                        <?php
                            if($my_date == $my_date) {
                                echo $my_date;
                            }
                        ?>
                    </th>
                @endforeach
            @endforeach
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
            <?php  
                $dates = Tblreportdate::with('tblreporttype')
                ->groupBy('fDate')
                ->get();
            ?>
            <?php
                $types = Tblreporttype::all();
            ?>
                    @foreach($types as $type)
        <tr>
                        <td width="200">{{ $type->fType }}</td>
                    @foreach($dates as $date)
                    <?php
                        $convert = $date->fDate;
                        $my_date = date('d', strtotime($convert));
                    ?>
                    <td width="100">
                        <?php
                            if($date->tblreporttype->id == $type->id) {
                                echo $my_date; 
                            } else {
                            echo " ";
                            }
                        ?>
                    </td>
                @endforeach
        </tr>
            @endforeach
    </tbody>

</table>
```

This is the output [image]